# Changing a C# delegate's calling convention to CDECL

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, calling-convention

I have had this problem with C# when I was using DotNet1.1

The problem is this. I have an unmanaged dll, which has a function which takes a function pointer (among other arguments). When I declare the DLLImport in C# code, I pass a delegate. But the delegates in C# have `stdcall` calling convention whereas the unmanaged function expects a `cdecl` function pointer. Thus my naive approach resulted in crashes. Then I found the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cdeclcallback.aspx Some guy wrote an excellent library that enables changing calling convention of the delegate by, as I understood, MSIL-hacking. Things went well, until...

I migrated to VS2008 and the new version of .NET. Under this version the abovementioned library doesn't work. I am not really a C# or .NET expert, and, to tell the truth, I barely understand what his library does (although it's open-source), so I don't even want to try to adapt it to new .NET. However I am hoping that newer version of C# has some better solution available for my problem.

So, SO experts, please help me with my pain in the buttocks :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

By default the p/invoke system wraps your delegate in a stdcall function. You can change the generated wrapper's calling convention by using the [`UnmanagedFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyDelegate();
```

Comment: Can I assign a normal C# function to it?

Comment: btw, you can do it in vb.net: <UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> 
Public Delegate Sub my_callback_function(ByRef v As my_struct)