# C# pInvoke to a C function

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I would be grateful for help with a problem I have been stuck on for a couple of days.

I have a native C++ function type declared so:

```
typedef STATUS (T_TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback) (
        PEventCallback function, // pointer to the customer callback 
        PVOID param              // custom data (returned in callback)
        );
```

where `PEventCallback` and `PEVENT` are declared like so:

```
typedef int (*PEventCallback) (PEVENT event, PVOID param); 

typedef struct
{
  int nEventId;
  void* pParam;
} EVENT,*PEVENT;
```

The C++ code provides a pointer to a function of that type as a global variable:

```
T_TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback* TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback
        = NULL;
```

which is initialized later, via this code:

```
#ifdef LOAD_PROC_ADDRESS
#undef LOAD_PROC_ADDRESS
#endif
#define LOAD_PROC_ADDRESS(handle,func) \
  if((func=(T_##func*)GetProcAddress(handle,#func))==NULL) \
  {\
      sMsg.Format( "Error occurs while loading entry point\n'%s'\n"\
                   "from detector DLL '%s'\n", GetName (), #func );\
      MessageBox(NULL, sMsg.GetBuffer(), "Load Proc Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);\
      return (false);\
  }

bool P5100EDllManager::LoadProc ()
{
    CString sMsg;

    HMODULE hDllHandle = GetHandle();
    if (hDllHandle == NULL)
    {
        return false;   // cannot load the proc if the dll has not been loaded
    }

    LOAD_PROC_ADDRESS(hDllHandle, TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback);
    return true;
}
```

I want to call the pointed-to function from C#.  For that purpose, I have defined a C# wrapper:

```
public delegate void TDICallBack(IntPtr callbackEvent, IntPtr pParam);
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback(TDICallBack callBack, IntPtr param);
public void RegisterEventCallback(TDICallBack callBack, IntPtr param)
{
  TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback(callBack, param);
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
TdiapiFacade.RegisterEventCallback(OnTdiCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);

public void OnTdiCallBack(IntPtr ptr, IntPtr param)
{
}
```

The `RegisterEventCallback()` seems to work successfully, but at the point where the callback function is supposed to be invoked, the app crashes. As you can see, at this stage I am not even unwrapping the parameters provided to the callback function.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Contrary to your assertion, the C code does not declare any function.  If it's valid C at all (which seems doubtful to me and to CDECL) then it declares `T_TED_AcppBoxDYN_RegisterEventCallback` as an *alias* for a function *type*.  Perhaps it's valid C++, but even in that case it must declare a type alias, not an actual function or function pointer of that type.

Comment: How `STATUS` is defined?

Comment: You can't call an unmanaged C++ instance function directly from C#. Because you don't have the `this` pointer. Also, your `TDICallback` delegate has to be Cdecl. You'll need the `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155180/changing-a-c-sharp-delegates-calling-convention-to-cdecl

Comment: typedef int STATUS; //!< Error code type

Comment: @Jim: The function he's trying to call doesn't appear to be a member function.

Comment: So the ultimate objective is to register a C# function as a callback to be invoked later from unmanaged C++?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The edit makes that clear, and also makes it clear that your answer is most likely correct.

Answer (score 2):

P/invoke doesn't allow access to exported data (variables) such as your function pointer.  You'll need a helper inside the DLL, either an exported function which wraps the function pointer, or one that returns it (the return type will be seen as a delegate inside C#).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input

I've resolved the issue, by modifying the registration of my callback from:

```
void RegisterCB()
{
    var ret = TdiapiFacade.RegisterEventCallback(OnTdiCallBack, new IntPtr());
    HandleError(ret);
}
```

to this:

```
private TDIAPI.TDICallBack callback;
void RegisterCB()
{
    callback = new TDIAPI.TDICallBack(OnTdiCallBack);
    var ret = TdiapiFacade.RegisterEventCallback(callback , new IntPtr());
    HandleError(ret);
}
```

This fixes the issue, now my callback is properly invoked.